# Custom Shipping Module Throwing Auto-Load Error

Tags: module, magento-1, shipping

I am receiving the following error, and I do not understand why. Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated, I have been banging my head against my desk for the past couple of hours, and I am not sure what to do next.

```
Warning: include(VMR/Czechposta/Model/Rate/Request.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /jlr/sites/mage/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

My config.xml looks like

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <VMR_Czechposta>
            <version>1.6.0.0</version>
            <depends><Mage_Shipping /></depends>

        </VMR_Czechposta>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <shipping>
                <class>VMR_Czechposta_Model</class>
            </shipping>
        </models>
          <default>
              <carriers>
                  <czechposta>
                      <active>1</active>
                      <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                      <model>czechposta/carrier_czechposta</model>
                      <name>Fixed</name>
                      <price>5.00</price>
                      <title>Czech Posta</title>
                      <type>I</type>
                  <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this     shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
                      <handling_type>F</handling_type>
                  </czechposta>
              </carriers>
          </default>
      </global>
</config>
```

And my Model looks like

```
class VMR_Czechposta_Model_Carrier_Czechposta
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{

    protected $_code = 'czechposta';
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $data
     * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result
     */
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $freeBoxes = 0;
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $freeBoxes += $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeBoxes += $item->getQty();
                }
            }
        }
        $this->setFreeBoxes($freeBoxes);

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        if ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'O') { // per order
            $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'I') { // per item
        $shippingPrice = ($request->getPackageQty() * $this->getConfigData('price')) - ($this->getFreeBoxes() * $this-    >getConfigData('price'));
        } else {
            $shippingPrice = false;
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier('czechposta');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('czechposta');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes()) {
                $shippingPrice = '0.00';
            }


            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array('czechposta'=>$this->getConfigData('name'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is the problem:

```
<models>
    <shipping>
        <class>VMR_Czechposta_Model</class>
    </shipping>
</models>
```

By adding that to your config.xml you just told Magento you have overwritten every model that starts with `shipping`. Basically now `Mage::getModel('shipping/...')` will look for the model in your module.
I think what you need is this:

```
<models>
    <czechposta>
        <class>VMR_Czechposta_Model</class>
    </czechposta>
</models>
```